# How to build openSSL?

Tags: installation, openssl, windows-7-x64

I want to share my knowledge with others, how to install openSSL from http://www.openssl.org/

I know some of people didn't get any problems with that, but I've got a few of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've got some problems with building openSSL, and I didn't find one post for few problems.

I downloaded openSSL sources from https://www.openssl.org/source/ (current version is 1.0.2d). I read INSTALL.W64 in the root directory, and tryed to build. I have win7 x64. It says I need perl. I downloaded and installed it. Then:

1. Win+R and type `cmd`

`cd WHERE_YOURS_OPENSSSL\openssl-1.0.2d
perl Configure VC-WIN64A
ms\do_win64a`

here I've met problem: "mI64 is not recognized..." Solution: before code above I should to run bat file. It placed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio X.X\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat.So, resulting commands are:

`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio X.X\VC\bin\x86_amd64
vcvarsx86_amd64
cd WHERE_YOURS_OPENSSSL\openssl-1.0.2d
perl Configure VC-WIN64A
ms\do_win64a
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak`

Then I've met new problem: "tmp32dll/x86_64cpuid.asm fatal error". I saw few "solutions" but help only one of 'em:

open file "WHERE_YOURS_OPENSSSL\openssl-1.0.2d\crypto\x86_64cpuid.pl" in text editor.Find the line "*STDOUT=*OUT;" and replace it like "*STDOUT=*FD;", above that line line it says: "open OUT,...." replace it to "open FD,....", save and close.

then, I deleted tmp dir (tmp32dll), and repeat all commands again. After that actions building will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've added my own guide for building OpenSSL 1.0.2d 64-bit on Windows with Visual Studio 2015 here:

https://ingehenriksen.wordpress.com/2015/11/22/building-openssl-1-0-2d-64-bit-on-windows-with-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 0):

How to build 64bit in VC-2015 OpenSSL 1.0.2n without NASM.

```
first startup ms build command 2015 

cd VC | if you are in programfiles x86/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
vcvarsall /?  | to see options if you need use sdk of Windows 10
vcvarsall x64 8.1 | standard option for VC-2015 64bit
cd \ | go to root of c:
cd openssl-1.0.2n | The source folder download extracted to c:\
perl Configure -no-asm VC-WIN64A --prefix=c:\openssl-64
ms\do_win64a
nmake -f ms/ntdll.mak
nmake -f ms/ntdll.mak test  | test are sometimes unnecessary
nmake -f ms/ntdll.mak install
```

to build the static library needed for libcurl static do in same folder:

```
nmake -f ms/nt.mak
nmake -f ms/nt.mak test     | test are sometimes unnecessary
nmake -f ms/nt.mak install
```